# Can't run sympy in python, though in cmd and in IDLE it says that it is installed

Tags: python, sympy

Sublime shows error:

```py
from sympy import divisors
a = input("Enter a number")
divisors_a = divisors(a)
print("The divisors of {} : {}".fromat(a, divisors_a))
```

Error:

```
from sympy import divisors                                                  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
```

I tried installing sympy again, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Which terminal command / IDE option are you using to run the code?

Comment: In `.fromat(a, divisors_a)` do you mean `.format(a, divisors_a)`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the sympy module is not found, which could indicate that the module is not installed correctly or it is not installed in the same environment where you are running your code.
You could try the following steps:

1. Reinstalling sympy with the following command - `pip install sympy`
2. If it is already installed, try upgrading it using - `pip install --upgrade sympy`
3. If none of the above steps work, try uninstalling and reinstalling sympy using - `pip uninstall sympy` followed by - `pip install sympy`.

Comment: Yes, misprinted

Comment: @Gideon_Ogunbanjo Tried all 3 steps, nothing. i'm running code in sublime text 3, doesn't understand what do you mean "not installed in the same environment where you are running your code"?

Comment: @Caridorc
 Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, and I believe this video can help you to sort out the answer. https://youtube.com/shorts/0qeoaaRSKcg?si=rIh8Uen09TSDQnRw

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).